# IMO 2014 - Problem 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

I have seen that a couple of other questions have been posted on this. I am however interested in understanding a conclusion of the part of the proof to this question that I have seen elsewhere.

> Let $a_0<a_1<a_2< .. $ be an infinite sequence of positive integers. Prove that there exists a unique integer $n \geq 1$ such that
>   $$\tag{1}
>   a_n < \frac {a_0 + a_1 + \cdots + a_n} {n} \leqslant a_{n + 1}\;.
> $$

1. First of all, I am a bit unclear about the formulation of the sequence. Can the sequence be (an example): $\{1,3,5,100,234,351,...\}$. This sequence can be made infinite and it satisfies the $a_0 < a_1 < a_2 < ...$ condition. Or does it have to be 'sequential': $\{5,6,7,8,9,10,...\}$? I would assume that people who compile these questions make it as clear as possible, in which case I am missing out on something...
2. And finally, the proof that I saw started by saying that for $n=1$ we have tat: $a_1 < \frac{a_0+a_1}{1}$, this is understandable and trivial. But then it moves on to say that $a_1 < \frac{a_0+a_1}{1} \nleq a_2$. And the reason is that because otherwise the condition in $(1)$ would be satisfied (we have found $n=1$ and now we only need to show that it is unique). I agree that the question would not be on an olympiad if that was not the case, but that is not a valid mathematical reason... And now my confusion goes back to the precise definition of the sequence. Because if the sequence can be of the form $\{1,5,100,..\}$, then clearly $a_2 \geq a_0 + a_1$.

Comment: For 1, I'm quite sure it doesn't have to be sequential since it didn't say so. ${1,3,5,100,234,351,...}$ is a valid sequence.

Comment: A sequence is just an ordered set of numbers. They don't have to be consecutive, an arithmetic progression, etc.

Comment: I agree. In that case,  the proof I have seen cannot be correct

Comment: `the proof that I saw` You'll need to quote that proof in full for the question to be answerable.

Comment: $\frac{1+2+10}{2}$ isn't bigger than 10

Comment: Check http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2014_IMO_Problems/Problem_1 for a valid proof.

Comment: Literally just googled it :)

Comment: @Macavity Again, in that solution.. How is $a_{n+2} \geq a_{n+1}$. We have that the condition is strict: $a_0 < a_1 < a_2 <... $

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal  don't see the problem. $x>y \implies x \geq y$.